# Getting error while trying to open CD Tray in C++

Tags: c++, cd, tray

I cannot seem to be able to open the CD Tray.
It pops me some error with 'extern C' what does extern mean too?

Thanks!
Here's the image!
[Error in C++ opening CD Tray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4qbF.png)

Comment: I'd recommend that you copy+paste your source code and the error messages (as text) into your question. It will make it easier for people to find in future if they have a similar problem, and it means your question doesn't depend on an external link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"extern C" isn't really relevant here. The actual problem is the "unresolved external" errors on your call to `mciSendString()`. It means the compiler knows that the function exists (because the declaration has presumably been included in a header). However, it doesn't know where the implementation of that function is.

That usually means you haven't linked to a required external library. [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757161%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) indicates that you need the `Winnmm.lib` library in order to use `mciSendString()`. You need to specify that library in your project settings, which is usually under something like "Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies" in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3):

extern "C" tells the C++ compiler that the function declaration is a C function.  This matters at link time because the C++ compiler generates symbols that are "mangled". For more details on extern "C", see this post:  [In C++ source, what is the effect of extern "C"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/in-c-source-what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c)

Your underlying problem is not related to extern "C" though.  The linker is telling you that the C function mciSendString() is not found.  Your project needs to link to Winmm.lib.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, the error you are getting indicates that the definition of the function `mciSendString` cannot be found. If you read the requirements for `mciSendString` on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757161%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you'll see that it requires the `winmm.lib` library. Below is a demonstration of how you can use the Visual C++ preprocessor directive `pragma comment` to add the library:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#pragma once
#include<windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "winmm.lib")
#include <stdlib.h>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    mciSendString(L"set cdaudio door open", 0, 0, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: that fixes the problem, but it would be better to provide some explanation with your answer rather than giving only-code answers.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include an explanation that does not repeat too much, what others have already said.